# FastCGI doesn't execute scripts in parallel

Tags: perl, fastcgi

I'm still new to FastCGI. I can't get my head around on how to execute Perl scripts in parallel.

The problem is that when I open the same URL multiple times in a browser, for example:

```
http://example.com/myscript.pl
```

which just contains a busy loop:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

for (my $i = 0; $i <= 700000000; $i++) { }
```

then only one FCGI process is running, using 100% CPU, even though my webserver is spawing 8 of them (I'm using lighttpd.)

However, if I copy the script to another file, and then open them both:

```
http://example.com/myscript.pl
http://example.com/myscript_copy.pl
```

Then two processes are running, 50% CPU each. I just don't understand that.

My Perl FastCGI dispatch script (meaning the script that the webserver spawns 8 times), is this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use CGI::Fast;

{
    while (new CGI::Fast) {
        do $ENV{SCRIPT_FILENAME};
    }
}
```

One solution would be to spawn a new Perl process for every script that is requested by the clients. But then this would defeat the purpose of FastCGI; I don't want to spawn dozens of Perl processes per second for every incomming request. That's way too much overhead.

How's Perl supposed to work with FastCGI? I must be doing something fundamentally wrong here...

In case my lighttpd configuration is important (maybe there's some mistake there), it's this:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_fastcgi",
)

server.document-root = "/var/www"
server.upload-dirs   = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog      = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file      = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username      = "www-data"
server.groupname     = "www-data"

index-file.names     = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                         "index.htm", "default.htm",
                         " index.lighttpd.html" )

url.access-deny      = ( "~", ".inc" )

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl"

dir-listing.encoding = "utf-8"
server.dir-listing   = "enable"

compress.cache-dir = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype  = ( "application/x-javascript", "text/css",
                       "text/html", "text/plain" )

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

fastcgi.server = (
    ".pl" => ((
        "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/perl-fcgi.socket",
        "bin-path" => "/usr/local/lib/cgi-bin/perl-dispatcher.fcgi",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 8,
    ))
)
```

Comment: If you have pool of max 8 procs, incoming 9th request is going to wait some time in order to be served. This can be solved be either speeding up the script if possible, or by increasing the pool.

Comment: @mpapec You should read the question again from the beginning :-) The problem here is that there's wait time starting from the second request already. There's 8 processes in the pool, but only one of them is used. The other 7 do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> One solution would be to spawn a new Perl process for every script
>   that is requested by the clients. But then this would defeat the
>   purpose of FastCGI; I don't want to spawn dozens of Perl processes per
>   second for every incomming request.

You appear to have misunderstood FastCGI.  Each process still only handles a single request at a time, so you can't handle dozens of requests simultaneously without creating dozens of processes to handle them.

What FastCGI actually gives you is that it can keep processes around to be reused for a *later* request or it can be configured to spawn processes in advance, before an actual request comes in that requires them.  Both of these features help to minimize the need to spawn processes on-demand while a client is waiting for a request to be handled, but they do not change the need to have one server process to handle each incoming request.

Comment: The problem is that the other 7 processes don't do anything. Only the first one is running. As I mentioned in the example, if I do two requests to http://example.com/myscript.pl, only one of the processes runs, even though I did two requests. What I would have expected instead is that two processes would handle each example.com/myscript.pl request.

Comment: That is not true that FastCGI allows each process to handle a single request at a time. That only depends on the implementation. The original FastCGI specification allows fetching new connections while the old ones are still not completed. It also allows multiplexing, sending/receiving data packages for different connections, completing them in parallel. At first they only considered multi-threading for utilizing these capabilities, but since then one can also use async techniques or polling (event-based techniques).

Comment: @CrouchingKitten - Interesting details on the spec. I didn't know that. But, today (6 years after the original question/answer), does the combination of Apache mod_fastcgi and Perl CGI::Fast (the implementations the OP was using) allow a single process to handle multiple requests concurrently? Or is there another set of FastCGI-based implementations for Perl which would allow this? If so, I'd love to see another answer posted with the details of how to do it.

Comment: @DaveSherohman On Apache there are 2 modules one can choose from. One is what you mentioned: `mod_fastcgi`, and the other is `mod_fcgid`. Only `mod_fastcgi` supports parallel processing (In my opinion this means that `mod_fcgid` doesn't properly implement the specification.). I don't know much about Perl, but my feeling is that it would need to use threading, which is complicated. The simplest way to develop a single-threaded fastCGI application is to use NodeJS with promises. (And avoiding `await`, which would block.)